# How to share media using Twilio Conversation API? - in .NET MAUI

Tags: twilio, maui, twilio-api, twilio-conversations, maui-android

I am developing an android chat application using Twilio Conversation API in.NET MAUI.
I don't get a sample in [Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/media-support-conversations). How to share media here?

I tried this [stack overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73355460/twilio-conversations-send-image).
It doesn't work for my case. I don't find any method like ConversationMessageResource.Create() as mentioned here.